# EclipseLink : Criteria Builder API and NOT IN clause

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm working with a criteria builder query and having an issue with including a 'not in' clause.  Here's my code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = AppUtils.EMF.PU_ROSTER.getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Members> cq = cb.createQuery(Members.class);

    Root<Members> root = cq.from(Members.class);
    Expression<Integer> idExp = root.get(Members_.memberId);

    if (currentFlag) {
        Predicate p = idExp.in(getCurrentUserList());
        cq.where(cb.and(p));
    } else {
        Predicate p = idExp.in(getCurrentUserList());
        cq.where(cb.not(cb.and(p)));

    }

    cq.where(cb.and(root.get(Members_.refMemberStatus).get(RefMemberStatus_.id).in(AppUtils.MEMBER_STATUS_ACTIVE)));

    List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList();
    orderList.add(cb.asc(root.get(Members_.lastName)));
    orderList.add(cb.asc(root.get(Members_.firstName)));

    cq.orderBy(orderList);

    Query q = AppUtils.EMF.PU_ROSTER.getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);

    return q;
}
```

the `getCurrentUserList()` function returns a `List<Integer>` collection.  My issue is regardless of whether my 'currentFlag' is true or false, I get the same result set.  Looking at the queries in the debugger they look exactly the same.  I put a breakpoint on currentFlag and it has the proper value and the appropriate code is in fact processed based on it's value, yet the queries are identical.

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2016-06-06 07:41:34.26--ServerSession(845434732)--Connection(733865607)--SELECT MEMBER_ID, ALT_PHONE, CDATE, CITY, DEGREE, DEPARTMENT, EDATE, EMAIL, FAX, FIRST_NAME, INSTITUTION, LAST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, MOBILE_PHONE, MODIFIER, PAGER, PASSWORD, PHONE, PHONE_EXT, RAW_PASSWORD, STATE, STREET1, STREET2, USERNAME, ZIP, MEMBER_STATUS_ID FROM ROSTER.MEMBERS WHERE (MEMBER_STATUS_ID IN (?)) ORDER BY LAST_NAME ASC, FIRST_NAME ASC

[EL Fine]: sql: 2016-06-06 07:42:09.191--ServerSession(845434732)--Connection(733865607)--SELECT MEMBER_ID, ALT_PHONE, CDATE, CITY, DEGREE, DEPARTMENT, EDATE, EMAIL, FAX, FIRST_NAME, INSTITUTION, LAST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, MOBILE_PHONE, MODIFIER, PAGER, PASSWORD, PHONE, PHONE_EXT, RAW_PASSWORD, STATE, STREET1, STREET2, USERNAME, ZIP, MEMBER_STATUS_ID FROM ROSTER.MEMBERS WHERE (MEMBER_STATUS_ID IN (?)) ORDER BY LAST_NAME ASC, FIRST_NAME ASC
```

I've tried putting my cb.not clause in various places, but it never seems to make a difference.

As per the comment below (thank you **Neil Stockton**), I updated part of the above code with the following:

```
if (currentFlag) {
        Predicate p = idExp.in(getCurrentUserList());
        cq.where(p);
    } else {
        Predicate p = idExp.in(getCurrentUserList());
        cq.where(cb.not(p));

    }
```

with no change in resultset or generated query..

Comment: whats with the "cb.and(p)" ? why not just put "p" ?! Also put what JPA provider this is, since they likely all do not generate the same SQL

Comment: I'm using the latest version of org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider as my provider

Comment: I originally had it without the cb.and(p) clause but it made no difference.  I'm new to working with the CB API, so if my code looks a bit screwy, please let me know, and I do appreciate it..  --  Just tried it without the cb.and(p) and no change in results.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you again, Neil!!  You got me thinking more about it, and I figured out what was going on..  Here's my solution:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = AppUtils.EMF.PU_ROSTER.getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Members> cq = cb.createQuery(Members.class);

    Root<Members> root = cq.from(Members.class);


    Expression<RefMemberStatus> activeExp = root.get(Members_.refMemberStatus);
    Expression<Integer> idExp = root.get(Members_.memberId);

    Predicate activePredicate  = activeExp.in(AppUtils.MEMBER_STATUS_ACTIVE);

    if (currentFlag) {
        Predicate p = idExp.in(getCurrentUserList());
        cq.select(root).where(p, activePredicate);
    } else {
        Predicate p = idExp.in(getCurrentUserList());
        cq.select(root).where(cb.not(p), activePredicate);

    }


    List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList();
    orderList.add(cb.asc(root.get(Members_.lastName)));
    orderList.add(cb.asc(root.get(Members_.firstName)));

    cq.orderBy(orderList);

    Query q = AppUtils.EMF.PU_ROSTER.getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);

    return q;
```

It turns out when I set the where clause, it does not append to the property with new, but completely overwrites the value (Duh!)...  So I created the appropriate predicates for all of my criteria, and watched it work.  If there is a more dynamic way to do this, please feel free to let me know.  I'm just figuring this stuff out...